# storage size of DIR variable is not known

Tags: c, io

The code of the faulty function is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#define _ISDIR 1729
#define _ISFILE 431
#define _EXIST_ERR 611
#define _BUF_LEN 512
unsigned int fod(char*);
unsigned int fod(char *name){
    DIR check_dir;
    check_dir=opendir(name);
    int openf=open(name,O_RDONLY);
    if(check_dir!=NULL){
        return _ISDIR;
    }
    if(openf!=-1){
        return _ISFILE;
    }
    return _EXIST_ERR;
}
```

When I compile it with gcc 12.1.1, I get the following error:

```
copy.c:14:9: error: storage size of ‘check_dir’ isn’t known
   14 |     DIR check_dir;
      |         ^~~~~~~~~
```

How do I fix it? the function parameters are right, everyone says that this is how a directory should be opened. How do I fix it?

Comment: Who is "everyone"?  Anyone who says that is how it should be done is wrong.  `opendir` returns a `DIR *`, not a `DIR`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't compile because `DIR` struct is not fixed and you need to use a pointer to `DIR` instead. Also, `opendir` returns `*DIR` too. So replace this:

```
DIR check_dir;
```

With this:

```
DIR *check_dir;
```

You can check the return type by reading `opendir` manual page. The function is declared like this:

```
DIR *opendir(const char *name);
```

(Notice the return type)

Answer (score 1):

You can't declare an *object* (variable) of type `DIR` - like the `FILE` type, the definition of `DIR` is hidden.  You can only declare a *pointer* to `DIR`:

```
DIR *check_dir = opendir(name);
```